# How does Typescript 2 enforce non-nullable types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-typing, typescript2.0

I know a general explanation is that the compiler does static type checking, but what methods specifically does the compiler use to verify that no nullable types accidentally come into play?

Answer (score 6):

The nullability/undefinedness checking is just a change in how the type system models types. As usual, this all happens during the typechecking phase and nothing is in the emitted JavaScript to enforce this at runtime.

Anyway, you can think of a *type* as a *domain of values*. For example, the domain of `boolean` is usually just the two values `true` and `false`. `string` is an unbounded domain that contain strings like `"hello"` and `"world"` and every other string.

TypeScript checks that when a value is used in some type position, that value is in the domain of that type. For example, `true` is not in `number`'s domain, so it's illegal to try to use `true` where a `number` is expected.

In TypeScript without strict null checking, `null` and `undefined` *are in the domain of every type*. So the type `boolean` actually has *four* values: `true`, `false`, `undefined`, and `null`. As people usually discover, this is bad, because `undefined` and `null` don't behave exactly like `true` and `false`. For things with properties and methods, it's worse, because `substr` exists as a method of every value in the domain of `string` *except* `null` and `undefined`, so it's really annoying.

In TypeScript *with* strict null checking, `null` and `undefined` move out of the domain of every type and into their own types. Now the value `null` cannot be used in a place where a `string` is expected, because it's no longer in `string`'s domain. The type `string | null` now represents a value which might be some member of the `string` domain *or* the special value `null`.

This explanation is adapted from [Anders Hejlsberg's talk from Build 2016 starting around 44:30](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881) and as you might imagine, he does a better job explaining it than I do, especially because he has some nice slides to accompany it.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is completely compile side; all the static typing is lost when it is converted into JavaScript. There is nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
let foo: { myProperty: string } = { myProperty: "g" }; // myProperty is non-nullable

foo["myProperty"] = undefined; // bypass type checker!
```

Comment: That's correct, but that code throws a compile error with strict null checking though—"Type undefined is not assignable to type string." It doesn't bypass the type checker.